# Is there any problem in this task? (molecular formula of a gas inside a cylinder)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas, gas, molecules

I got this task:

A cylinder of volume V₁ = 2 L filled with gas of mass m = 7.48 g at T = 10 °C and under pressure P₁ = 2 bar

1. Calculate the amount of gas substance in the cylinder.
2. Infer the molecular formula of a gas? The following gas formulas are given: CH₄, N₂, CO₂, H₂
3. What is the number of molecules of this gas inside the cylinder?

I tried to answer 2nd question, but I couldn't because we know:
M(C) =12 g.mol-1, M(O)=16 g.mol-1, M(H)=1 g.mol-1, M(N)=14 g.mol-1

Then: M(CH₄)=18 g.mol-1, M(N₂)=28 g.mol-1, M(CO₂)=44 g.mol-1, M(H₂)=2 g.mol-1
and when you calculate it using:$n = \frac{m}{M}$ you can't find any of the previous results.

Look at my answer:
$P.V=R.T.n$ $$n = \frac{P. V} {R. T} = \frac{2.10⁵. 2} {8,31. 283}=170$$
$$170 = \frac{7,48}{M}$$ $$M = \frac{7,48}{170}=0.044$$

Comment: What did you get for the answer to #1?  Did you remember to convert the temperature into Kelvin?

Comment: The problem works out with the given values and the solution is one of the given molecules. You can calculate the amount of substance using the ideal gas law. Then you can calculate the Molar mass using the given mass and calculated amount of substance. Common errors are wrong units, did you make sure your units are consistent and properly converted ?

Comment: How many moles of gas did you calculate from the ideal gas law?

Comment: i found 170 mol

Comment: 2liters=0.002 m^3

Comment: Chet Miller has shown you your error and the reason you are off by a factor of 1000